# Convert array of hex to array to ASCII (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, hex, ascii

I want to convert this array of hex to array of ASCII.

I have tried to convert the array to string and using a function to convert hex string into ASCII, does not meet my expectation.

```js
var name = [4d,55,48,41,4d,4d,41,44,20,4e,41,5a,52,45,45,4e,20,42,49,,4e,20,5a,41,49,4e,55,44,49,4e];

name=hex2str(name);

function hex2a(hexx) {
   var hex = hexx.toString();//force conversion
   var str = '';
   for (var i = 0; (i < hex.length && hex.substr(i, 2) !== '00'); i += 2)
     str += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hex.substr(i, 2), 16));
return str;
}
```

**Expecting output:**

```
name = [M,U,H,A,M,M,A,D, ,N,A,Z,R,E,E,N, ,B,I,N, ,Z,A,I,N,U,D,I,N]
```

Comment: This looks like PHP not JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all `4d` is not a valid hex in javascript, you will need to append the `0x` prefix to mark it as hex, then you can map over the array & execute [`String.fromCharCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode)

```js
const name = [0x4d, 0x55, 0x48, 0x41, 0x4d, 0x4d, 0x41, 0x44, 0x20, 0x4e, 0x41, 0x5a, 0x52, 0x45, 0x45, 0x4e, 0x20, 0x42, 0x49, 0x20, 0x4e, 0x20, 0x5a, 0x41, 0x49, 0x4e, 0x55, 0x44, 0x49, 0x4e];

const result = name.map(hex => String.fromCharCode(hex));

console.log(result);
```